# Error :The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, remix, modifier

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

contract modifierExample{

    address admin ;

    constructor() public {
        admin == msg.sender;
    }

    modifier isAdmin {
        require(admin == msg.sender,"you are not the owner");
        _;
    }

    modifier isExp(uint exp) {
        if(exp >= 5)
        _;
        else
        revert("you are not experienced");
    }

    struct employeeDetails{
        uint iD;
        string name;
        uint age;
    }

    mapping (uint => employeeDetails) getDetailsByNum;

    function enterDetails(uint number,
                          uint iD,
                          string memory name,
                          uint age) public isAdmin isExp(5) {
                              employeeDetails memory EmployeeDetails = employeeDetails(iD,name,age);
                              getDetailsByNum[number] = EmployeeDetails;
                          }

    function getDetailsByNumber(uint number) public view returns (employeeDetails memory) {
        return getDetailsByNum[number];
    }

}
```

Why did I encounter this error?????
After entering the details it is throwing me an error as mentioned below

transact to modifierExample.enterDetails errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "you are not the owner".
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your `enterDetails()` function uses the `isAdmin` modifier.

As per the following code, any function that uses the `isAdmin` modifier, can be executed only by the address that deployed the contract.

```
address admin ;

constructor() public {
    admin == msg.sender;
}

modifier isAdmin {
    require(admin == msg.sender,"you are not the owner");
    _;
}
```

You're getting the `you are not the owner` error because you're trying to execute the function from some other address than the `admin`.